# Signing iOS xcarchive with a new provisions

Tags: ios, sdk, certificate, ios-provisioning

I have an `xcarchive` file that some changes made to him and I want to sign it for distribution. (It already was signed with our certificates)
When I first tried it after downloading all certificates and provision from Apple I got an error :

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and
>   failed to do so because of the following issues: Your account already
>   has a valid iOS Distribution certificate........ You can also revoke
>   the current certificate and request one again.

In my member center I had 2 provisions for Enterprise, I revoked the last one and generated new one.

Now I getting a new message :

> No matching provisioning found for "Applicataions/myAppName.app None
>   of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements:
>   application-identifier, beta-report-active, keyachain-access-groups.
>
> The selected team "my team..." is different from the team "6hjfhGHR44"
>   originally to build this item.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I have the same issue!

Comment: No, I got the all project clean, and signed it again.